# Display array of objects in table

Tags: arrays, angular, html-table, ngfor

I'm trying to display a list of objects in a table. But its only displaying the first row

This is the code I'm using

```
<table >
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>partId</th>
        <th>partName</th>
        <th>partDesc</th>
        <th>partTypeCode</th>
        <th>createdBy</th>
        <th>updatedBy</th>
        <th>createdDate</th>
        <th>updatedDate</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       
      <tr *ngFor="let part of allParts;">
        <td ><span>{{part.partId}}</span></td>
        <td><span>{{part.partName}}</span></td>
        <td ><span>{{part.partDesc}}</span></td>
        <td><span>{{part.partTypeCode}}</span></td>
        <td ><span>{{part.createdBy.firstName}}</span></td>
        <td ><span>{{part.updatedBy.firstName}}</span></td>
        <td ><span>{{part.createdDate | slice:0:10}}</span></td>
        <td ><span>{{part.updatedDate| slice:0:10}}</span></td>
       
      </tr>
    
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

[only first object visible in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo3zY.png)

When I use it in li tag as below it shows all the rows

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let part of allParts">{{part |json}}</li>
</ul>
```

[all objects visible in ul](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2fDk.png)

allParts

```
{ "partId": 1, "partName": "", "partDesc": "", "createdBy": { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "email": "john.doe@gm.com", "password": "P@ssw0rd!", "companyName": "GM", "id": "abc123" }, "updatedBy": null, "partType": { "partTypeCode": "pt1", "partTypeDesc": "pt1desc" }, "createdDate": "2023-01-03T22:13:24.180+00:00", "updatedDate": null, "quantity": 1 }, { "partId": 2, "partName": "", "partDesc": "", "createdBy": { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "email": "john.doe@gm.com", "password": "P@ssw0rd!", "companyName": "GM", "id": "abc123" }, "updatedBy": null, "partType": { "partTypeCode": "pt1", "partTypeDesc": "pt1desc" }, "createdDate": "2023-01-03T22:13:54.966+00:00", "updatedDate": null, "quantity": 1 },{ "partId": 3, "partName": "", "partDesc": "", "createdBy": { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "email": "john.doe@gm.com", "password": "P@ssw0rd!", "companyName": "GM", "id": "abc123" }, "updatedBy": null, "partType": { "partTypeCode": "pt1", "partTypeDesc": "pt1desc" }, "createdDate": "2023-01-03T22:14:20.081+00:00", "updatedDate": null, "quantity": 1 }
```

What should I change in order to display all the objects of the array in the table

Comment: Please attach your data as JSON snippet to the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Yong Shun I edited and added data now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `updatedBy` was `null` and you can't access `firstName` from `null` as below:

```
<td><span>{{part.updatedBy.firstName}}</span></td>
```

You need to apply [`?.` optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to stop accessing nested property when detect it is null.

```
<td><span>{{part.updatedBy?.firstName}}</span></td>
```

Or working with `*ngIf`

```
<td>
  <span>
    <ng-container *ngIf="part.updatedBy">
      {{ part.updatedBy.firstName }}
    </ng-container>
  </span>
</td>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fw9g3c?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: You are welcome. I updated the answer that you can handle with *ngIf directive as well.